# Minecraft Biome / Spawnpoint shifted

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

My friends and I have had an SMP-server for nearly 6 weeks and everything worked very well. No mods and no plugins so there can't be any problems related to them.

After about 3 weeks our normal area changed a bit. for example:

- Our island we've became an ice-island.
- The desert is now covered in snow
- The grass changed in color.

So the biome seems to have changed.

Not to mention the spawn point is now 100 blocks from where it was originally, and it is also covered in snow and ice where previously it wasn't.

As if this wasn't bad enough, after a huge crash of our server host the same thing happened again. Our "normal" areas changed more and more in ice and snow and the spawn-point is now about 300 blocks away.

So it seems that the biomes shifted. I, with my nonexistent programming skill, would say that some data or code for our biome has changed, but I don't know how to fix it. Is there a data editor or other program that will allow me to fix this?

I've read in another question that a backup restore would be the best, but the last backup we made is a VERY long time ago, nearly our whole city would be erased. I would like to avoid that option.

I've read a lot of threads on the internet but no one knows why this happens or doesn't understand the problem. Any suggestions? I'm pulling my hair out over this one.

Comment: It's not a bug. Global warming in Minecraft makes worlds have sudden shifts like these.

Comment: But I don't think that global warming changes the spawn point. :D

Comment: Possible Duplicate: [Minecraft Biome Modification? (SMP)](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/22890/minecraft-biome-modification-smp/22909#22909)

Answer (score 2):

If the biomes shifted it's probably due to a corrupted "seed" (just a long number) which seems to happen quite easily when the server crash. If you have an old save that still is ok you can get the correct seed from that save, and then edit your current save and set the correct seed.

It's really easy to read and set seeds with [LolEdit](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/23902-loleditor/). You just open the save in the editor and modify the seed field.

If you have explored new areas while the seed was corrupted you might also get problems with "sliced walls". Check my slighty longish answer in [this thread](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/22890/minecraft-biome-modification-smp/25980#25980) for a solution to that.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this happen before, but it was thought to be a problem with a mod. Have you tried using MCEdit to transfer your city to a new world? This should solve the problem, unless it happens again.

Comment: Ah okay, I talked with a mate of mine. The server-provider got a mod to repair destroyed chunks to prevent server laggs. And he used it a few weeks ago. Is it possible to change a "biome-data" ? Maybe a old biome-data to our today world. But it changed again without using this mod.

Comment: I've seen something similar.  No bad chunks, I respawned probably 150 blocks from where I should have and I found a bunch of ice where it didn't used to be.  The terrain around the ice is unchanged, it's just the water froze over.