# If I delete an existing chunk with MC Edit in my pre-1.8 save, will the new landscape in 1.8 line up with it?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

As Omokoii's answer to [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/28801/will-new-minecraft-b1-8-features-e-g-villages-and-ruins-appear-in-existing-wor) suggests, you can use MC Edit to delete existing chunks in an old save so that, once 1.8 is out, those chunks will be generated anew, and they should respect the new version's additional landscape and other world-building features, like villages and the new biome. However, Ullallulloo pointed out that random seeds will generate different worlds in 1.8 than they used to, so deleted chunks will not be recreated exactly as they were.

Does that mean that new chunks will not line up seamlessly with old chunks? Just how abrupt will the transition from the old landscape to the new landscape be?

Comment: In case anybody ends up looking at this problem later, I've run into this exact problem, but not quite. I generated a new world in 1.8 and converted it for multiplayer, but somewhere along the way I've managed to break the seed, because it did generated several broken chunks, giving me in some places rather severe borders, and rather clean ones in others. It doesn't look good any way you cut it though.
In simple cases I was able to take Bukkit and WorldEdit, and brush paint out the nasty segments, but this seems to be a rather time-consuming solution. It's the best you're going to get I think.

Comment: The rest of spektre1's comment continues as follows: "You can find worldedit here, but it does require bukkit, so you'd need to load it into an MP server instance if you're playing SP. http://wiki.sk89q.com/wiki/WorldEdit I find it easier to run a local listen server personally. Then if I wanna play with a friend I can. In my case, I fixed my seed issue and now I'm trying to see if there's a way to delete chunks within the world, or force the server to regenerate an existing chunk."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"How abrupt" depends entirely on the particular chunks in question, and is impossible to predict to boot. There's really no way to know until you try for yourself.

If you're unsure you want the potentially very obviously misaligned chunks, you can always backup your world before deleting it, reverting if the border does not line up particularly smoothly.

Comment: Indeed it's not possible to know much yet. My _guess_ (and hope) is that there will be some kind of save game conversion just like when biomes where introduced.

Comment: @Omokoii - I think with biomes, every chunk needed biome information, and since it didn't have it *before* the introduction of biomes, it had to generate some to be able to render the game at all. If the new features are simply due to changes in the world generation, I don't expect a conversion to be possible.