# Will witches' huts be generated in a minecraft world that was created before they were (will be) added?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Will new Minecraft features appear in existing worlds?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/28801/will-new-minecraft-features-appear-in-existing-worlds)

I'm a bit confused about how updating works. I imagine the already existing chunks will remain the same but new ones may contain the witch's hut, or do I have to create a brand-new world?

I'd hate to do that, I put weeks into my underwater fortress :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that they will spawn in newly generated areas. By that I mean they may be spawned when the game create more chunks.